# how do i host my web-component as a library served over CDN?

Tags: javascript, build, polymer, web-component, lit-element

I'm hoping to host a single javascript file that contains my webcomponent and exposes it, but I get the error

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-html". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

What tool should I use to convert the webcomponent source to something that can be consumed over CDN as a single JS library?

The project is Open Source and hosted here: https://github.com/glade-software/glade-element

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use rollup, and make sure the "module" property in my package.json points to the file outputted by rollup, to be consumed by unpkg downstream!